# Deleting/Removing a rectangle from a vector C++ (SDL2)

Tags: c++

I'm building Breakout for a project. I'm nearly done but I have one issue, deleting the bricks from the vector when they have taken enough hits. This is the function I'm currently working with:

```
void HandleBlockCollision()
{
    for (auto &p : enemies)
    {
        p.hits--;
        if (p.hits == 0)
        {
        enemies.erase;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Error  1   error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator>> std::vector>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator>>,std::_Vector_const_iterator>>)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'SDL_Rect' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator>>'

I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Cheers!

Comment: `enemies.erase;` isn't a thing. If you wanted to call `enemies.erase(it);` check the dupe.

Comment: I've tried different variations of it like:
enemies.erase(p.pos);
enemies.erase(*p.pos);
p.erase(enemies):
etc but nothing seems to work.
P.S. What is the dupe?

Comment: It doesn't work with `auto`, as mentioned check the marked duplicate question.